# Trouble setting ports for forwarding

Tags: iptables

I am on ubuntu and trying to add the following rule
`sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp — dport 80 -j REDIRECT — to-port 3000`

At first I get the error `Bad argument -` So I guess it's `-to-port` missing a trailing hyphen and change it to this:

`sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp — dport 80 -j REDIRECT —-to-port 3000` I then get the same error. I guess this is related to the `dport` so I change the command to this:

`sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp —-dport 80 -j REDIRECT —-to-port 3000`

And now I get the error `Bad argument —-dport`. Not sure where to go from here. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the exact line you are using, you are using two different dashes.  The first is hex 97, Em Dash, and the second is hex 2d, dash, the minus sign.  Re-do the line like this, using, dash, the minus sign.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Comment: wHATTTTTTT wow. how did you spot that?

Comment: Em Dash and En Dash have two different lengths. Looking on screen here it looked like two different widths.  I pasted your command into a text editor and flipped to hex mode.

Comment: A slight correction, while correct that an em dash is longer than an en dash, both of these are different from a hyphen ([or dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)), which is the character that is required for these command line flags.  Sometimes something in the copy/paste translates these sequential `--` characters into the en dash.